# How to subsample/resize an image like in whatsapp

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

When sending an image through whatsapp, you can see the image you are sending  in an imageview **scaled very very well**

for example, i sent two images to my friend

- size of first image  : **1296 pixels** X **2304 pixels**
- size of second image : **1920 pixels** X **1080 pixels**

**this images are too big therefore whatsapp has to scale them before showing them to me in an imageview**

- size of first image after being scaled by whatapp **333 pixels** X **339 pixels**
- size of second image after being scaled by whatsapp **333 pixels** X **187 pixels**

As you can see the width is the same only height differs. i have tried to figure out how whatapp scales this images, but my methods **gives me an image with a different dimensions far from whatsapp's ones**

**Method 1**

```
private void resizeImage(){

Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                      d("image url is " + selectedImage);
                      InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                       BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream,null, options);
                      imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                      imageWidth = options.outWidth;

                      options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,reqWidth,reqHeight);
                      options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream,null, options);

}
private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth , int reqHeght){

    int height = options.outHeight;
    int width = options . outWidth;
    d("width is "+ width + " height is "+ height);
    d("required width is "+ reqWidth + " required height "+ reqHeght);
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(height > reqHeght || width > reqWidth){

        int heightRatio = Math.round((float)height/(float)reqHeght);
        d("height ratio is "+ heightRatio);

        int widthRatio = Math.round((float)width / (float) reqWidth);
        d("width ratio is "+widthRatio);

        inSampleSize = (heightRatio > widthRatio)? heightRatio :widthRatio;
    }
    d(" insample size is "+ inSampleSize);
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

**Output for first image using the above method :** Smaller(< 333) width, very big height(>339. it's 579!!)

**Second method**

```
private Bitmap scaleToFitWidth(Bitmap b, int width){
  float factor = width/b.getWidth(); // width is 333

  return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width,(int)(b.getHeight() * factor),true)
}
```

**Output of first image in second method:** image height is very very big!

**Question** Does anyone knows how to scale images very well like whatapp **Across all devices**?(i would like to be the same as whatsapp if possible)

**EDIT: whatsapp Images**

**My huawel phone**

[image: image is huawel]

**samsung tablet**

[image: image in samsung talet]

Comment: i also wondered about this

Comment: what if you set factor as constants for example 0.5 ?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira  i think it will be even worse. first of all, i think whatsapp uses some dimensions to ckeck if image is greater than those dimensions

Comment: @DanielNugent    what do you mean my picasso?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira let me try it out and i will tell you if it worked

Comment: @ShvetChakra   if i find an answer i will let you know

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira     There must be a way to calculate maximum width and height. if i set them like in the link you gave me, the image will appear very big in small devices

Comment: i accidentally deleted my comment. can you post the link again?

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira     This is the link https://gist.github.com/akshay1188/4749253#file-whatsapp-image-compression

Comment: 333 pixels X 339 pixels

333 pixels X 187 pixels 2 example value not enought to formulate i think

Comment: @user2859375   i din't understand your comment

Comment: @gikarasojokinene i try to find whatsapp scale formula but we have a one value height bigger than weight  may be more example help us to formulate , i m sory my english

Comment: @DanielNugent  when i use picasso, the image is still very big. i thought it will automatically resize like in whatsapp.

Comment: @DanielNugent  picasso can't effeciently provide a scaled image. it work better when you give it a scaled one. my problem is scailing

Comment: You just need to use the resize() method with centerCrop(), take a look at this: https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: @DanielNugent  i really appreciate your great help..... but i have 1 more question. how can i come up with dimensions to use in resize() method that will fit in all devices which will run my app?. e.g tablets, small phones e.t.c. is there a good technic i can use to get those dimensions so that i can use them to scale the image?

Comment: You can really just use one value for all screen sizes, just make sure that it looks good on larger screens

Comment: @DanielNugent   suppose i select 400 X 400. this dimension might be ok for one device but too big for a small samsung phone and a very big samsung tablet. is there a way i can use screen size to compute demension?.

Comment: If you mean how big the ImageView shows on the screen,  you can use the layout.  Use `dp` for dimensions, and if you really need to, use different layouts for large and small screens.

Comment: @Shvet Chakra  i  got the answer. check it below

Comment: @gikarasojokinene thank you I will look at it .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can checkout this code it works same as you wanted [WhatsApp Like Image Compression](https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/0cd97d012934531f1266). This code has been modified according to my usage.
Using this code will provide you :

- Low Size Images around **100kb** without playing with image quality.
- High pixel images will be scaled down to *maxWidth* and *maxHeight* without loosing its original quality.

Original Article : [Loading images Super-Fast like WhatsApp](http://abdelhady.net/2015/03/28/android-loading-images-super-fast-like-whatsapp-part-2/)

Demo  :

[Original Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7SVudPeYXS7WGM2X2xsWEs0Tkk/view?usp=sharing) :   Size - 3.84Mb Dimensions - 3120*4160

[Compressed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wifGu.jpg) : Size - 157Kb  Dimensions - 960*1280

**Edit 1:** You can also make a *custom Square ImageView* which extends `ImageView` Class. [SquareImageView](https://gist.github.com/xingrz/c95cdedf57f45f60dd28)

Comment: let me try it and i will tell you the outcome

Comment: **There is one major mojor issue:**   how can i come up with maxWidth and maxHeight that will not be bigger in one device or smaller in onother?.   this is the most difficult challenge am facing

Comment: Whatsapp also uses the same _maxWidth_ and _maxHeight_ as in code.i know because  I have tested it manually by running test cases of different images to whatsapp. And then checking out each image size and dimensions in `sent` folder.

Comment: when i send an image in my huawel phone, the image is resized very well. the person am sending to is using a samsung tablet. **and the size of image(or imageview) in his phone is not the same as the size of image(or imageview) in my phone**.  **i have edited my question. see photos**

Comment: if the use the same maxWidth and maxHeight, **how do they come up with the size that will be shown to the user in the imageview?.**

Comment: @gikarasojokinene it depends upon the height and width provided to `ImageView`. And the `dip` provided to imageView will have varying height and width depending upon phone (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) as pixel size varies on diff phone

Comment: let me try playing around with imageview maxWidth and see if it will work

Comment: it's really difficult to come up with a good size of the imageview. i try to set maxWidth to my phone's dpi which is 240, but the height is very big.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene My suggestion for you would be using the Custom Square Image View and setting margin left and right to that imageView

Comment: what do you mean by custom square image view? do you mean like i set width to 50dp and height to 50dp ?

Comment: Yeah I mean make a custom `ImageView` which extends ImageView Class and using it. https://gist.github.com/xingrz/c95cdedf57f45f60dd28

Comment: brother, your idea of setting an custom square imageview worked. if possible, edit your answer and include that comment. i higly appreciate your help. merry merry chrismas. wish you happy holidays

Comment: @gikarasojokinene same to you bro. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @ Vipul Asri    am really struggling to find a good tutorial that can guide me on how now i can send my image after compressing it to onther person using my app.  do you know a good working tutorial?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene is that person on your app? what type of app are you working on. Give me some brief regarding your app so that i am able to tell you the solution

Comment: @ Vipul Asri    am working on an app that one can use to send messages and media(photos and videos). am able to send messages using google GCM. now am implementing the media part of it. so i would like to know how i can send images, videos, and audios. if you know how i can send any or all of this media i will be very thankful vipul

Comment: @gikarasojokinene best way to implement will be to upload the image using multipart to your backend and then using imageUrl sent to sender use image loading libraries like Picasso or  Glide or Fresco to download image/media on sender device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98783/discussion-between-gikarasojo-kinene-and-vipul-asri).

Answer (score 0):

> How to subsample/resize an image like in whatsapp

- You can do it by simply using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) as follows. Replace the
  value **500,500** with your required image quality.

  ```
  Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
              .load(uri)
              .asBitmap()
              .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(500, 500) {
                  @Override
                  public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                      bitmap = resource;//this is the required bitmap
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(resource); 
                  }
              });
  ```
- If you want to save the Bitmap as a file, use the following method

  ```
    private File savebitmap(String filename) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    File file = new File(filename + ".png");
    if (file.exists()) {
       file.delete();
       file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".png");
       Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
    }
    try {
       // make a new bitmap from your file
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getName());

       outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, outStream);
       outStream.flush();
       outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return file;
  ```

  }
- To include Glide in your project, add the following to your gradle
  file

  ```
   repositories {
   mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven    Central
   }

   dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
   }
  ```