# Android Bitmap Compression insufficient and causing OutOfMemoryError crashes

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, bitmap

I am basically trying to compress and pass a Base64 representation of an image selected by a user however the apps crash on different phones with OutOfMemoryError problems. Here's my compression and conversion code:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

This process is also painfully slow and causes the app to crash sometimes.

Here's an exception I got:

```
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5035548 byte allocation with 5011320 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:625)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2477)
```

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 2;  //you can also calculate your inSampleSize
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options); //changed line code
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Note :** Using `android:largeHeap="true"` for your application doesn't considered to be a ideal solution.

Here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

here's the complete link of the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

**Edit 1:** For Efficient scaling of Images like **WhatsApp Image Compression** checkout this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34367979/3140227)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. How's the quality of the output image after compression using this solution? Is it affected greatly?

Comment: Looks good on average images but the more HD the image, the longer it takes.. can we speed this up a bit?

Comment: yes you can for that you have to scale the images. Check out `Edit 1`.

Comment: And how do I set 'options' to an already existing Bitmap? without decoding I mean

Comment: Vipul that constructor doesnt exist :/

Comment: @Earthling sorry my mistake, according to my knowledge yo can't apply it on already created bitmap. And for scaling of images do see edit1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recycle your bitmap after used it. And set the bitmap to null too. If you want run the garbage collector.

Comment: bm.recycle(); bm=null; System.gc();

Answer (score 0):

this approach wont work well for very large pictures, say picture taken from a camera. a 13 mp photo is 4128x3096x3 bytes which is about 40 megabytes. that is the size of bitmap alone. if you are creating the base-64 representation on the fly, it would take another 40 megabytes and some more, since base-64 string costs more bytes to store than comparable raw byte array (bitmap).

do you really need to turn it into base 64? if for example you want to upload it can you do it directly via rest api or multipart post request.

if you cant do that perhaps you can split the operation, like per 1 MB, or instead of writing that string into memory you can write it to file and append it after every 1 MB operation?

Comment: Which do you think is the better solution? Multipart uploading or Base64? Which method does facebook, instagram, etc follow?

Comment: @Earthling `Multipart` is better solution of uploading the image as converting image to string using `base64` increases its size by **33%** resulting into taking more bandwidth.

Comment: @VipulAsri Do you have any sources I can look in to? I need to upload it via a Rest Service Post

Comment: @Earthling this implementation is using Volley : https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/b96488c612c1f150a1da