# Resize image URI to 100k

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I am retrieving image from URI. But it is taking too much time to load. My average file size is 500k. How do I reduce that to 100k:

```
// Here is the code where I am displaying image URI

// The retrieval of URI using Picasso

 public void setImage(final Context context, final String image) {
     final ImageView postImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.allPostImage);
        with(context).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(postImage, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(postImage);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: visit this link http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subsample/resize an image like in whatsapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350755/how-to-subsample-resize-an-image-like-in-whatsapp)

Comment: You can certainly *render* the image smaller or compress it further after it downloads, but it will still take just as long to download.  You want to resize the original source image as it exists on the server.  There's really no other solution.

Comment: It is not on a server i think. Its on the device itself. As setImageUri() will not download it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

    InputStream imageStream = null;
    try {
        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                imageUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    try {
        stream.close();
        stream = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Use this to compress your image size.

Comment: The png file size will be bigger then the original jpg file. The bitmap is unaffected and original size.

Comment: replace png with jpeg and 100 with 50

Comment: That does not change anything for the bitmap. And why loading a jpg, convert to bitmap and convert to jpg again? And doing nothing with that byte array? The 50 would make a smaller jpg file with bad quality but the bitmap is still the same.

Comment: also changed the 100 to 50,it will decrease the size.